# I can't loop through a vector of objects when trying to overload the output operator

Tags: c++, object, for-loop, vector, iterator

I have a class CPerson

```
class CPerson
{
private:
    string name;
    string egn;
public:
    CPerson() {};
    CPerson(string getname, string getegn)
    {
        name = getname;
        egn = getegn;
    }
bool operator < (const CPerson &obj)
    {
        ...
    }
    bool operator ==(const CPerson &obj)
    {
        ...
    }
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const CPerson &obj) //извеждане в поток - конзола
    {
        ...
    }
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, CPerson &obj) //четене от поток - конзола
    {
        ...
    }
    friend ofstream& operator <<(ofstream& out, const CPerson& obj) // извеждане в поток - файл
    {
        ...
    }
    friend ifstream& operator >>(ifstream& in, CPerson& obj) // четене от поток - файл
        {
...
        }
```

I made another class CCity which has a vector of objects CPerson

```
class CCity
{
private:
    string city_name;
    vector <CPerson> people;
public:
    CCity() {};
    CCity(string filename)
    {
        string name, egn;
        ifstream file(filename);
        file >> city_name;
        while (file >> egn >> name)
        {
            people.push_back(CPerson(name, egn));
        }
    }
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const CCity& obj)
    {
        vector<CPerson>::iterator iter;
        for (iter = people.begin(); iter != people.end(); iter++)
        {

        }
    }
};
```

I am trying to overload the output operator so I can output my vector of objects but I get the error "left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union". I can't see anything wrong with my code. I have include  and

Comment: Why do you have an overload for both `ostream` AND `ofstream`? Anyway, for your question, `people` does not exist in that context. It's `obj.people` at that point. Also, it'll be a `const_iterator`

Comment: Thanks it worked. To your question - because I want to read from a file and write to a file. Why would it need to be a constant iterator?

Comment: you only need `ostream` and `istream` operators to write/read from/to any stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At very first:

```
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const CCity& obj);
```

does not define a member function! Declaring the function (operator) as `friend` makes it a free-standing one, even if defined inside the class. So there's no `people` object inside. You need to refer to by `obj.people`!

Then why do you declare `iter` in front of the loop? Do you need the iterator for any reason afterwards? If not, prefer keeping it local to for loop. Then you can additionally let the type get deduced: `for(auto iter = ...`. `auto` will additionally cover another error: `obj` is const, so `obj.people` is const as well. And the `begin` overload for constant objects won't return an `iterator`, but a `const_iterator`! Be aware that there are two versions of begin:

```
iterator begin();
const_iterator begin() const; // <- that one will be called on const objects!
```

Would you break the loop in between? If not, you could use a range based for loop as well: `for(auto& person : obj.people)`. Again the type of `person` gets deduced, as we explicitly told `auto` to be a reference, type will be `Person const&`.

Whichever variant you chose, you now can output the person:

```
out << *iter;
out << person;
```

Assuming they were public, you could access the person's attributes as well:

```
iter->name;
person.name;
```